# Python XML- getting what is between two nodes

Tags: python, xml, minidom

Here is my xml file

```
<gui>
<object class="wxPanel" name="new"> 
     <object class="wxBoxSizer"> 
        <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient> 
        <object class="sizeritem"> 
            <object class="wxTextCtrl" name="a"></object>
        </object>  
            <option>1</option> 
            <flag>wxEXPAND</flag> 
        </object> 
</object>
</gui>
```

I want to get exactly what is in between the gui tag

So I would want this:

```
<object class="wxPanel" name="new"> 
     <object class="wxBoxSizer"> 
        <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient> 
        <object class="sizeritem"> 
            <object class="wxTextCtrl" name="a"></object>
        </object>  
            <option>1</option> 
            <flag>wxEXPAND</flag> 
        </object> 
</object>
```

I am currently using

```
minidom.parse("path to xml").getElementsByTagName('gui')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

However this does not work with getting xml as a string.

Comment: Have you tried `.innerXML` or `.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try toxml

```
gui = minidom.parse("path to xml").getElementsByTagName('gui')[0]
gui.getElementsByTagName('object')[0].toxml()
```

Comment: Good but it still keeps the <gui> and </gui> tags

Answer (score 0):

You could be using a parser that would be more appropriate. `ElementParser` would do the trick pretty well:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('path/to/xml.xml')
gui  = tree.getroot()
ET.tostring(gui.getchildren()[0])
```

Now this all looks a bit hackish, and probably isn't going to be very reliable anyway, regardless of which parser you use.